# OpenGL strange bug rendering nothing from VBO

Tags: debugging, opengl, vbo

I have this code for an OpenGL project i'm doing and it draws nothing:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_terrainVBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3,        GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

// Bind the buffers
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_cubeVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_cubeIBO);

// Draw the elements on the GPU
glDrawElements(
        GL_TRIANGLES,
        3*12,
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
        0); // SIZE IN BYTES, REMEMBER!

// Disable the vertex attributes (not necessary but recommended)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

But when i remove the line

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_terrainVBO);
```

the cube model is rendered perfectly. Now the `g_terrainVBO` do exist as i checked its size in the buffer using

```
// verify buffer size
int nBufferSize = 0;
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &nBufferSize);
int originalVertexArraySize = ( nBufferSize / sizeof(TerrainModel::Vertex) );
cout << "Buffer size: " << originalVertexArraySize << endl;
```

and the size shows up correctly.

ANyone know what is the problem here? What is causing my terrain model VBO to bug the rendering and nothing shows (not even the cube)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect to happen here?

If you setup the pointer relative to the terrain, then it is going to draw the terrain. `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_cubeVBO);` does nothing in this code.

However, assuming this is your only drawing code, then if you remove `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_terrainVBO);`, the ***next*** time you draw it is going to use `g_cubeVBO` (since the pointer uses whatever is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` at the time it is called).

Rendering the terrain using the indices from the cube does not make much sense either.

#### Add this *after* you bind your cube VBO to restore some sanity to the world:

```
glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So dumb of me, i thought the order in which u set the pointer does not matter as it would only set the states on the GPU until draw call has been called.
I see now... Then the remaining problem is to find out why my terrain is not shown, it does impact the performance but see no graphics... but at least i see the cube now